# How to keep custom indentation for binary operation in Eclipse formatter

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

I was testing the eclipse formatter to try to have something that match my current coding format in Java. However, I was not able to find an option to keep current indentation for string concatenation (binary operation). For example, if I want to write this string (SQL query):

```java
// Current code, I want to keep this format
String query = "select "
            + "a, "
            + "b, "
            + "c, "
        + "from table "
        + "where "
            + "a = 1 "
            + "and b = 2 "
        + "order by c";
```

Everything will be wrapped at the same indentation (I checked the option *Never join already wrapped lines*)

```java
// Formatted code
String query = "select "
        + "a, "
        + "b, "
        + "c, "
        + "from table "
        + "where "
        + "a = 1 "
        + "and b = 2 "
        + "order by c";
```

Which I find less readable.

I saw there was an option to turn off formatter for portion of code, but I would like to know if there is an already built-in option for my need.

Comment: Note: A Java 15 "text block" would be more readable

Comment: @greg-449 I just checked Java 15 text blocks. I would accept this as an answer, but I don't use Java 15 unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java 15 onward a "text block" would be most readable:

```java
String query = """
    select
      a,
      b,
      c,
     from table
     where
      a = 1
      and b = 2
     order by c
     """.replace("\n", "");
```

which produces:

```
select  a,  b,  c, from table where  a = 1  and b = 2 order by c
```

which has a few extra unimportant blanks.